# Eloquent WHERE LIKE clause with multiple columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm implementing a search bar that can search customers by first name, last name, or both. So, for example, `Mike Hizer` would be matched by `Mike`, `Hizer`, `zer`, `Mike Hizer`, etc. Here's what I came up with:

```
Customer::where(
    DB::raw('concat(first_name," ",last_name)'), 'like', "%{$request->search}%"
)->get()
```

It works. But is there a more Eloquent approach to combine these two columns (`first_name` and `last_name`) without resorting to the DB facade? Would something like

```
->where(['first_name','last_name'], 'like', "%{$request->search}%")
```

be possible to achieve?

Comment: Have you checked out Laravel Scout? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scout It provides a simple, driver based solution for adding full-text search to your Eloquent models.

Comment: @Denis Priebe Yea, I should look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use the `DB` facade you could use the whereRaw method:

```
Customer::whereRaw('concat(first_name," ",last_name) like ?', "%{$request->search}%")->get();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice, that's exactly the approach I used. I was just wondering if Eloquent has that functionality out of the box, without `DB` or raw queries. Thanks anyways

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = User::where('id', '=', '2');

$query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', "%$search%");
$query->or_where('last_name', 'LIKE', "%$search%");
$users = $query->get();
```

Try this way..

Comment: laravel doesnt have or_where, should be orWhere

Comment: This does not yield th expected Result, as parts of first and last names in the search query may not be identified.