# Eloquent WHERE LIKE clause with more than two columns

Tags: php, laravel

I've been trying to do a query in Laravel that in raw SQL will be like this

```
"SELECT * FROM students WHERE (((students.user_id)=$id) AND (((students.name) Like '%$q%') OR ((students.last_name) Like '%$q%') OR ((students.email) Like '%$q%')))")
```

I follow this thread ([Eloquent WHERE LIKE clause with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121065/eloquent-where-like-clause-with-multiple-columns))  and it worked fine, but only with two columns Ej:

```
$students = student::where(user_id, Auth::id())
         ->whereRaw('concat(name," ",last_name) like ?', "%{$q}%")
         ->paginate(9);
```

But if I add more than two columns then the resultant variable is always empty, no matter if what is in the variable $q match with one or more columns:

```
$students = student::where(user_id, Auth::id())
         ->whereRaw('concat(name," ",last_name," ",email) like ?', "%{$q}%")
         ->paginate(9)
```

I am pretty sure I am missing something but i can't find what it is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Concat returns null if any of the fields null. Is not this the problem? Considering it worked with 2 the third field is the suspicious one...

Comment: Ok so that’s the problem, but how can I fix it, because I allow people to store the emails but is not mandatory, but this is meant to filter a table with a simple search so I want it to filter taking into account all the columns, that is to say that if one of the is null do not convert all the others in null

Comment: Using `concat_ws` instead of `concat` can help to tackle NULLs properly. But mbozwood's answer seems to be more Eloquent friendly for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$students = student::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where(function($query) use ($q) {
    $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%')
        ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%')
        ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%');
})->paginate(9);
```

The above Eloquent will output SQL similar to

```
"SELECT * FROM students WHERE students.user_id = $id AND (students.name like '%$q%' OR students.last_name Like '%$q%' OR students.email Like '%$q%')"
```